# openlayers cluster strategy - exhibiting custom icons for clusters of 1 feature

Tags: openlayers

i have a page that displays a **vector layer** imported from a **kml file** (basically like the the [sundials example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html)).  it works perfectly well, both using fixed strategy ONLY, as well as using both fixed and CLUSTER strategies simultaneously.

i would like to create a **hybrid display**, whereas **"clusters of 1 feature"** would be displayed with the original **custom icon** contained in the KML file under `<Style><IconStyle><Icon><href>img/arrowRed.png`, for example.

right now, **if i use cluster strategy, clusters of 1 (feature) are displayed using the default icon** (yellow disk).

i would rather not use any plugins or libraries that aren't standard openlayers.   **any suggestions?**

below a part of the original javascript code using clusters (remove the cluster strategy declaration `new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()` and custom icons are displayed just fine):

```
var urlKMLClient = 'KMLClientsAll.kml'; 
var layerKMLClient = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Clients", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster(), refresh],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: urlKMLClient,
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            })
        })
    });
```

[image: WITHOUT CLUSTER]

see Client custom icon (green marker) gives way to cluster default icon (yellow disk) below

[image: WITH CLUSTER]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({threshold:2})` this allows thad isolated points they are not in a cluster.

(is a repetition of the answer at the same question in GIS forum)

Answer (score 0):

found the solution in [this GIS question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29425/how-to-access-the-icon-of-a-feature-retrieved-from-text-in-a-vector-layer):

change the cluster strategy to MORE THAN 1.  the above code would become:

```
var clusterStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({ distance: 35, threshold: 2 });
var urlKMLClient = 'KMLClientsAll.kml'; 
var layerKMLClient = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Clients", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), clusterStrategy, refresh],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: urlKMLClient,
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            })
        })
    });
```